# GattServiceProvider.StartAdvertising fails : Bluetooth device issue?

Tags: c#, bluetooth-gatt, windows-creators

I'm trying to publish a GATT Server following this tutorial :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-server

The code fails on my Asus Zenbook with onboard bluetooth 4.0 :

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007013C) : Bluetooth device doesnt support peripheral role

which is confirmed by this call :

BluetoothAdapter bta = await BluetoothAdapter.GetDefaultAsync();
bta.IsPeripheralRoleSupported is set to false

Do you think it is a driver issue, API issue or missing hardware feature ?

Somebody knows a bluetooth LE dongle I could manage with the new .Net API ?

I already bought a Bluegiga BLE dongle and it doesn't seem compatible...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm looking for a BLE that can act as a server too

Comment: Same here, upvoted

Comment: I suspect the issue is not the dongle.   Peripheral role support seems to be something windows doesn't support on a desktop device, regardless of the capabilities of the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

This works on desktop PCs. Some PCs might not support peripheral role, so you would need to update the `IsConnectable` flag to `false` on `StartAdvertising` to prevent it from advertising as peripheral role, assuming it fits your application:

```
GattServiceProviderAdvertisingParameters advParameters = new GattServiceProviderAdvertisingParameters
{
    IsDiscoverable = true,
    IsConnectable = false
};
serviceProvider.StartAdvertising(advParameters);
```